# How to call jQuery function from React typescript component?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, typescript, adminlte

I want to call AdminLTE javascript object from my .tsx file but got an error like this:

> [ts] Property 'AdminLTE' does not exist on type 'JQueryStatic'.

In AdminLTE.js file, the declaration looks like:

```
$.AdminLTE = {};
```

In my typescript file, I called using:

```
componentDidMount() {
  $.AdminLTE.layout.fix(); // Got error
}
```

Is there anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options:

**Option 1:** Install the typings for the `AdminLTE` plugin if they exist. (I can't find the typings for this in npm, you may have to contact the plugin owner if typings exist for this)

**Option 2:** Declare `AdminLTE` as `any`. You can access `AdminLTE` without any type restrictions:

```
declare var $: JQueryStatic & {
    AdminLTE: any
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but when `console.log($.AdminLTE);`, it returned `undefined`. Seems the **AdminLTE** object does not refer to the real module.

Comment: Make sure you are importing `admin-lte` in your code for your plugin to be actually available at runtime. The answer is only to fix compile-time type checking.

Comment: I've imported the reference of AdminLTE's app.min.js before I load my app script. But, the $.AdminLTE still undefined. The compile time checking was solved, but the run time still in issues.